Methodology to study the Electromagnetic Wave Absorption Capability by the Magnetic Materials
I want to study how the absorption capability of the electromagnetic wave (EMW) by the magnetic materials. As far as I know, all DFT (density functional theory) codes do not have the function to evaluate the absorption capability of EMW by the magnetic materials.
I wonder how to study such properties (EMW absorption capability) by the magnetic materials. Is it done with Landau-Lifshitz-Gilbert (LLG) formula or some other methods?
Would anyone please recommend any proper methodology to study such properties to me?
Thank you in advance.
